# SML how to change String after isSubstring comparison

Tags: string, substring, sml, smlnj

I am currently learning SML/NJ due to a program that uses mostly a gui for basic input, but SML input for advanced options. 
 
I want to compare whether one string is a substring of another. 
 
If the condition is true then the full string should "just" be returned or assigned to a new variable.
 
For Testing purposes I used an online compiler, because I get almost zero feedback from the other program.

Relevant Code Snippet:

```
 fun SString(sub:string, str:string):string = 
     if isSubstring(sub, str) = TRUE then str 
      (* str should be returned , no errors*)
                                 else val p2:string="nope"; 
                    (* no return or adjustable(fixed)return /without data*)

   val p1 = "sender,time,data"
   val p2 = "sender" 

 print(SString(p2,p1))
```

So far I am stuck now.

My main questions are:

1. Can I actually create a new variable in a function?
2. What is the best practice in this case?
3. In some online docs I read that it isn't possible to assign a new value to a variable once assigned. 
    
   Should my function rather have following form with inner bindings and `let decl in expr end *var`?

```
  fun newstr:string(sub:string,str:string) = 
    let val n = isSubstring(sub,str)
    in 
    end *sub
```

Thanks in advance

Relevant results of the compilation:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
- stdIn:4.33-4.44 Error: syntax error: deleting  ELSE VAL ID
- stdIn:4.52-4.61 Error: syntax error: deleting  EQUALOP STRING SEMICOLON
```

P.S. I added fitting tags, feel free to remove/adjust them

Comment: Try [A gentle introduction to ML](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/manual.html), or [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/isml/book.pdf), or [ML for the working programmer](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html)

Comment: thank you A gentle introduction to ML is a great reference.It seems to do the trick.                                                                                     I already read the second one, but that is just confusing with ommiting parts of the code structure.

Answer (score 0):

A gentle Introduction to ML gave me a great understanding of SML, except for some cryptic codes and type conversions.

```
val p1:string = "weather,maps,translate"; 
val p2:string = "maps";

fun SString(sub:string, str:string) = let 
    in case (String.isSubstring sub str) of 
    (true) => str ^ ",pie"
    | (_) => "nope"
    end; 

val a = SString(p2,p1);
val b = String(p1,p2);
```

The executed result of above code:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
- val p1 = "weather,maps,translate" : string
  val p2 = "maps" : string
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]  
[autoloading done]
val SString = fn : string * string -> string
val a = "weather,maps,translate,pie" : string
val b = "nope" : string
```